# Accessing two properties from query

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I am attempting to:

1. Query AD for accounts expiring within a date range of 90 days from current day.
2. Write-Output to include the expiration date and the user's email address.

Issue:
I'm only able to figure out how to pull one property. That is, either the expiration date of user's email address.

Here is my Powershell script. Thank you in advance.

[image]

Comment: Copy paste your code here instead of screenshot of it

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please don't post screenshots of code - post your code as raw text instead! If you're having trouble formatting it correctly, just paste it at the bottom [of the existing post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/67709579/edit) and we'll help you fix it :-)

Answer (score -1):

You need to run `get-aduser -Properties *` to have all properties at once. After that it's all script logic.